# Ordering list of users through association with a Scope - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a syntax error with my scope and search trough many example on stack overflow but unable to resolve it, your help would be much appreciated.

- i am trying to create a scope that orders the list of users by the company name
- could one kindly advise me on the correct way to write a scope where i am able to display the list of users but order them by their companyname

> models

```
user.rb
belongs_to :company
scope :company_order, ->() { joins(:company).where('company.companyname desc') } 

company.rb
has_many users
```

> schema

```
users
t.string   "name",
t.string   "email",
t.integer  "company_id"

companies
t.string   "companyname",
```

> views file

```
<% @users.company_order.each do |user| %>
  <div class="tablerow">
    <div class="tablecell">
      <div>e: <%= link_to user.name, '#' %></div>
      <div>t: <%= link_to user.email.tel, '#' %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablecell">
      <div>Company</div>
      <div><%= user.company.companyname %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my scope: `scope :company_order, ->() { joins(:company).where('company.companyname desc') }`  and tried calling it in the views `<% @users.company_order.each do |user| %>`  but i get the below syntax error:

> error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "desc": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "users"."company_id" WHERE (company.companyname desc)
```

> could one kindly advise me on the correct way to write a scope where i
>   am able to display the list of users but order them by their
>   companyname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER` should not be inside the `where` method, but inside the `order` one:

```
scope :company_order, ->() { joins(:company).order('companies.companyname desc') }
```

`where` is for query conditions, also note the table name in plural.